# Create Sequence starting with maximum row count value of a table for HSQL

Tags: liquibase, hsqldb

I am trying to create a sequence with maximum row count value of some table. So far I could only do this

```
create sequence "mysequence" start with 1;
```

Instead of starting with one, I need to start with max row count value of a table. How to accomplish this in HSQL

Comment: You will need dynamic SQL for that. HSQLDB does not allow the "start with" (not starts with) value to be a query (and neither does ALTER SEQUENCE).

Comment: Can you please give that dynamic SQL solution?

Comment: You can find the max value and use the number in the CREATE SEQUENCE statement.

Comment: @fredt can you please post the dynamic sql for that?

Comment: You cannot do it with dynamic SQL in HSQLDB.

Comment: You can write a a few lines of Java code to SELECT the max value then generate the CREATE SEQUENCE string with the value and execute it.

Comment: I did it using java, thanks - @fredt